# How to interpret using Most Significant Bit of single byte - Pcapng time format "if_tsresol"

Tags: bit, pcap

I'm writing a library to parse a file format (pcapng) [documented here](https://pcapng.github.io/pcapng/#section_idb). There's one particular section I'm having trouble with, it's an option that defines how the `long` epoch/time variable should be parsed. The option `if_tsresol` is defined by a single octlet/byte, according to the spec:

> The if_tsresol option identifies the resolution of timestamps. If the
>   Most Significant Bit is equal to zero, the remaining bits indicates
>   the resolution of the timestamp as a negative power of 10 (e.g. 6
>   means microsecond resolution, timestamps are the number of
>   microseconds since 1/1/1970). If the Most Significant Bit is equal to
>   one, the remaining bits indicates the resolution as as negative power
>   of 2 (e.g. 10 means 1/1024 of second). If this option is not present,
>   a resolution of 10^-6 is assumed (i.e. timestamps have the same
>   resolution of the standard 'libpcap' timestamps).
>
> Example: '6'.

I'm happy with how either case works. E.g. for the first, if the value is '0' it represents seconds since 1970, '3' means milliseconds since 1970, '9' would mean microseconds etc.

I'm also happy with the second case, 10 would mean it's 1/1024 of a second, (i.e. nearly milliseconds), 20 would mean 1/1048576 of a second (i.e. nearly microsecond).

My confusion is over the "Most Significant Bit", and how to choose between these two. My understanding is the [Most Significant Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) is effectively the left-most bit in a bit sequence.

So, taking the first example, a value of '3' has the bits `00000011`, so the most significant bit is equal to zero right?

However, this first significant bit won't stop being zero until the whole byte is 128 or greater, in which case the second 'option' is meaningless as we're expecting a number from 10-30.

Should I be ignoring the first bit in the calculation of the byte itself? So:

```
00001010 = 10 which is 10 (option 1)
10001010 = 138 which is 10 (option 2)
```

and

```
00000110 = 6 which is 6 (option 1)
10000110 = 134 which is 6 (option 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be ignoring the first bit in the calculation of the byte itself?

Yes.  As the pcapng spec says:

> If the Most Significant Bit is equal to one, *the remaining bits* indicates the resolution as as negative power of 2 (e.g. 10 means 1/1024 of second).

so the first bit is a flag and the rest of the bits are the value, and you ignore the first bit when doing the calculation.